# Unable to find module 'collections/dict' when trying to use the library in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, module

I want to use a dictionary in my javascript program and from the http://www.collectionsjs.com/dict website I found that I can use

`var Dict = require('collections/dict');`

however it gives me the error

`[ts] Cannot find module 'collections/dict'`

I have NodeJs installed. What am I missing to have this library work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install this module

```
npm install collections --save
```